# Getting max value from a list with None elements

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nonetype

I'm trying to get maximal value from a list object that contains nonetype using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

LIST = [1,2,3,4,5,None]
np.nanmax(LIST)
```

But I received this error message

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Clearly `np.nanmax()` doesn't work with `None`. What's the alternative way to get max value from list objects that contain `None` values?

Comment: What about converting `None` to 0?

Comment: `None is not np.nan`

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, convert to a numpy array. Specify `dtype=np.floatX`, and all those `None`s will be casted to `np.nan` type.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None]

x = np.array(lst, dtype=np.float64)
print(x)
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,  nan])
```

Now, call `np.nanmax`:

```
print(np.nanmax(x))
5.0
```

To return the max as an integer, you can use `.astype`:

```
print(np.nanmax(x).astype(int)) # or int(np.nanmax(x))
5
```

This approach works as of `v1.13.1`.

Comment: Good to know that `np.array` with specified dtype converts `None` to `nan`. NumPy is full of surprises.

Comment: @MSeifert yes, the explicit type forces the conversion. Otherwise, it is stuck with `dtype=object` (shudder).

Comment: Yeah, I would have expected a `TypeError` (like in `float(None)`) though. :)

Comment: @MSeifert Added a version note. I'm unaware as to whether this continues to work in older versions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments from you all. I noticed that using your recommended method will generate an output of 5.0, is this a float64 object?

Comment: @ChrisT. Yes. Do you want an integer? Just convert it again: `print(np.nanmax(x).astype(int)) >> 5`

Comment: @COLDSPEED. No, I actually want a pure 'float', but I heard from a previous comment (can't find it, sorry) warning that float64 and float work quite differently. Hence, I am trying to ascertain this point.

Comment: @ChrisT. I don't think they work differently. For all practical purposes, they're the same. Try `x = np.array(lst, dtype=float)` and you get the same thing.

Comment: Though for a bigger list such as  `LIST*1000`, the list comprehension approach is still faster than this.  `nanmax` is fast, but `np.array(biglist, float)` takes time.  `np.fromiter(biglist, float)` is a bit faster.

Comment: @hpaulj I timed this for `LIST*1000`, `LIST*10000` and `LIST*100000` and it turns out the list comp is 20% faster always... interesting.

Answer (score 10):

One approach could be -

```
max([i for i in LIST if i is not None])
```

Sample runs -

```
In [184]: LIST = [1,2,3,4,5,None]

In [185]: max([i for i in LIST if i is not None])
Out[185]: 5

In [186]: LIST = [1,2,3,4,5,None, 6, 9]

In [187]: max([i for i in LIST if i is not None])
Out[187]: 9
```

---

Based on [`comments from OP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025724/getting-max-value-from-a-list-with-none-elements/46025745?noredirect=1#comment79011518_46025745), it seems we could have an input list of all `None`s and for that special case, it output should be `[None, None, None]`. For the otherwise case, the output would be the scalar `max` value. So, to solve for such a scenario, we could do -

```
a = [i for i in LIST if i is not None]
out = [None]*3 if len(a)==0 else max(a)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I tried that before and ran a for loop to generate the my output into a list, but received this error `max() arg is an empty sequence`.

Comment: @ChrisT. Is it possible that `LIST` contains only `None`s?

Comment: @MSeifert. Yes, and thanks so much for asking (I was thinking about this and was just about to open another question thread). How does one deal with such empty list?

Comment: @ChrisT. What's the expected output if there are all `None`s?

Comment: @ChrisT. In Python 3 `max` accepts a `default` argument, so you could use `max([i for i in LIST if i is not None], default=None)`, that will return `None` if all your values are `None` instead of failing. Of course you could also use another value as default.

Comment: It will be `[None, None,  None]`. I asked this because I am using wordnet's `.path_similarity()` function to measure the similarity between two synsets, and not every synset can get a match, hence, generating a `None`. For some synsets, they can't find a match at all and return `[None, None, ..., None]` with a length equal to their synset size. This causes problems when I was trying to get the max value out of a list of matching similarity scores as you saw above.

Comment: @ChrisT. That's interesting. So, if the input list has all None and it could have any number of elements, the output would be a list of three `None`s, otherwise it would be a scalar (the max value)?

Comment: Indeed, that is very likely, but I haven't thought about the scalar part.

Comment: @ChrisT. Added a section at the end of the post.

Comment: @Divakar, you mean discussing the `[None, ..., None]` problem?

Comment: @ChrisT. Yes, added a section to solve such a case, assuming I understood it :)

Comment: Ok, I will do that.

Comment: @ChrisT. I mean I added a section on solving such a case at the end of my solution/answer post. Check that out :)

Answer (score 8):

In Python 2

```
max([i for i in LIST if i is not None])
```

Simple in Python 3 onwards

```
max(filter(None.__ne__, LIST))
```

Or more verbosely

```
max(filter(lambda v: v is not None, LIST))
```

Comment: Don't use `filter` here. It would also discard zeros which could be a problem if you have `LIST=[-1, 0]`. You wouldn't expect it to return `-1` as maximum.

Comment: When you say "best", it would help if you also mentioned it's best by what criteria (it's not really clear).

Comment: use max(filter(None.__ne__, LIST))

Comment: This solution does not cover the case where the list is all None

Comment: @pigi5 If the list contains all `None`, you can use the `default` argument of `max()`

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I would do:

```
>>> max(el for el in LIST if el is not None)
5
```

It is superficially similar to the other answers, but is subtly different in that it uses a *generator expression* rather than a *list comprehension*. The difference is that it doesn't create an intermediate list to store the result of the filtering.

Comment: Though this generator route doesn't save time.

Comment: @hpaulj: I never said it did. ;-) In my benchmarks, the two approaches have similar performance (but one is O(1) memory whereas the other is O(n)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list-comprehension to first filter out Nones:

```
np.nanmax([x for x in LIST if x is not None])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I put your code into a for loop to generate the output into a list, but this, like other methods, also threw me an error `zero-size array to reduction operation fmax which has no identity`

Answer (score 1):

use [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to get rid of all the `None` of the `LIST`
We are taking advantage of the fact that, filter method takes two parameters. The first one is a function and the second one is an Iterable.
This function must return an element of the Iterable(provided as the second argument) which gets removed from the Iterable. We are passing None as the first argument thus all of the objects that are ***false*** (in this case `None`) of the Iterable (`LIST`) gets filtered out.

```
import numpy as np
LIST = [1,2,3,4,5,None]

filtered_list = list(filter(None, LIST))
np.nanmax(filtered_list)
```

**Edit:**  This won't remove 0 from the LIST

```
filtered_list = list(filter(None.__ne__, LIST))
```

Comment: `filter(None, ...)` also discards zeros. That could lead to problems if `0` would be in fact the maximum (e.g. `LIST=[-1, 0]`)

Comment: Yes, I saw in an earlier post using filter, but this also generated an error on my Python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more specific to take the `max` of numbers only you can use `filter` and the [numbers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html) abstract base class:

```
>>> import numbers
>>> filter(lambda e: isinstance(e, numbers.Number), [1,'1',2,None])
[1, 2]
```

Or, a generator version of this:

```
>>> max(e for e in [1,'1',2,None] if isinstance(e, numbers.Number))
2
```

---

Since this is Python 3, your error is the stricter comparison rules under Python 3:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 23 2017, 16:49:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1<None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Where Python 2 does allow unlike object comparisons:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 15 2017, 08:44:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1<None
False
>>> 1>None
True
```

So when you create a numpy array you are getting an array of Python objects:

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,5,None])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, None], dtype=object)
```

So numpy is using the underlying Python 3 comparison rules to compare an array of Python objects which is your error:

```
>>> np.max(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,None]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2252, in amax
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 26, in _amax
    return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

So you either need to filter out the `None` when you create the numpy array:

```
>>> np.max(np.array([e for e in [1,2,3,4,5,None] if e is not None]))
5
```

Or convert it to a numpy type that supports `nan` (and `np.int` does not have `nan`):

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4,5,None], dtype=np.float)
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,  nan])
```

But in this case, `nan` is the max value:

```
>>> np.max(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,None], dtype=np.float))
nan
```

So use `np.nanmax`:

```
>>> np.nanmax(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,None], dtype=np.float))
5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas DataFrame have their own function,

`list.idxmax()` return the index of max value by ignoring NaN value.
Look [this URl](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) for more info.